# how this list comprehension can be one liner in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to concatenate two strings into one few times and make a list with them.
What I want to do in Python3 code is basically like below

```
str = "This is a base string"
str_list= []
for i in ("ran", "dom", "str"):
    str_n = str + i
    str_list.append(str_n)
```

so I want to make this one line like below but it didn't work..

```
str_list= [str_n = str + i for i in ("ran", "dom", "str")]
```

How did this end up with error?

Comment: `[str + i for i in ('..', ...)]` — You just need the value of `str + i`, not the variable `str_n`. You can inline that in the original code too as `str_list.append(str + i)`. It's an error because assignment is a *statement*, and statements can't be used inside *expressions*.

Comment: Thank you so much. I still don't get why this ends up with syntax error when I return value instead of just str + i because I think both essentially do the same.

Comment: Your list comprehension needs to produce a *value*, not a *variable*, nor return that value/variable. The syntax is `[<value> for <var> in <expr>]`, and `<value>` automatically ends up as the values in the resulting list.

Comment: DON'T use `str` as variable name - `str` is reserved for the str-function.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the same with `str_list = [str+i for i in ("ran", "dom", "str")]` .

`str+i` itself return a value. No need to assign it into another variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do using list comprehension for the same output as your code:

```
str = "This is a base string"
str_list=[str+i for i in ("ran", "dom", "str") ]
print(str_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove "str_n =" from square bracket